# Postgres: Aggregate of Averaged Time Samples

Tags: postgresql

This is a bit of a SQL code golf post...

I have a table that contains a **timestamp** an **identifier**, and a **price**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ts_data  (
    ts TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, --timestamp
    metric INTEGER,                 --identifier
    usd DOUBLE PRECISION            -- price
);
```

Given the sample data:

```
INSERT INTO ts_data (ts, metric, usd)
VALUES 
('2018-08-21 01:00:00', 1, 5.00),
('2018-08-21 01:05:00', 1, 10.00),
('2018-08-21 01:10:00', 1, 15.00),
('2018-08-21 01:15:00', 1, 20.00),

('2018-08-21 02:00:00', 1, 25.00),
('2018-08-21 02:05:00', 1, 30.00),
('2018-08-21 02:10:00', 1, 35.00),
('2018-08-21 02:15:00', 1, 40.00),

('2018-08-21 01:00:00', 2, 1.00),
('2018-08-21 01:05:00', 2, 2.00),
('2018-08-21 01:10:00', 2, 3.00),
('2018-08-21 01:15:00', 2, 4.00),

('2018-08-21 02:00:00', 2, 5.00),
('2018-08-21 02:05:00', 2, 6.00),
('2018-08-21 02:10:00', 2, 7.00),
('2018-08-21 02:15:00', 2, 8.00);
```

**What I'm trying to do**

- Re-Sample the time-frequency by using **DATE_TRUNC** and average the price of the same truncated date per metric
- Calculate the SUM of all metrics per truncated date

**This query accomplishes what I want**

```
SELECT ts, SUM(usd) as usd FROM (
    SELECT metric, date_trunc('HOUR', ts) as ts, AVG(usd) AS usd
    FROM ts_data
    WHERE ts BETWEEN '2018-08-20 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-22 00:00:00'
    AND metric IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY date_trunc('HOUR', ts), metric
) samples
GROUP BY ts;
```

We get:

```
+------------------------------+
| ts                    | price|
+------------------------------+
| "2018-08-21 01:00:00" | 15   |
| "2018-08-21 02:00:00" | 39   |
```

Are there any more efficient or compact ways to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Your query looks good. Did you index for the conditions?

Comment: Query looks fine as Laurenz said but if i can ask why do you first make avg then sum the end result can be strange if in for example in on hour =1 you will have only one row with 1000 usd value, and on hour=2 you will have 1000 rows with avg value 1 after suming it you will have 1001 which says exactly nothing about your usd avg.

Comment: So these are repeated samples of the same value.  So if I have 20 samples in an hour, I want to know what the average of that hour was, before I SUM different samples from different metric-id's together.  Does that make sense?